# String to ByteArray

Tags: java

Can any one please explain the execution of this code? Thanks!

```
private   byte[]   convertStringToByteArray(String paramString)

{

   int i = paramString.length();

   byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[i / 2];
   for (int j = 0; j < i; j += 2)
   {
     int k = Integer.parseInt(paramString.substring(j, j + 1), 16);
     int m = Integer.parseInt(paramString.substring(j + 1, j + 2), 16);
     arrayOfByte[(j / 2)] = (byte)(m + (k << 4) & 0xFF);
   }
   return arrayOfByte;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you run and see? Go through debugger?

Comment: One thing you should do is give an attribution. Since you didn't write this code, you should edit your question and add the information about where the code is from and who the author is.

Answer (score 0):

This code tries convert hex-number from string representation to byte array.
String `FF` will be translated to single-byted array with first byte value `0xFF` (`255` in decimal).

Comment: Thank u Pavel....its just a piece of code from the program...The program is to read the data from RFID and Write the data into it...

Comment: When I write data like 4444555533332222..in turn am getting the value after clicking on write data as 44445555333322220000000000000000. How to delete last 16 zeroes?

Comment: It depends on your sources that are out of scope of current question - this method only converts hex number string representation to byte array.